# How to separate control disabled button in a nested form array in angular?

Tags: angular, button, formarray, formgroups

I have a problem for complex dynamic form. The problem is that I cannot disabled each session button. The rule is that the maximum of each session has 4 quota. If it reach 4 quota, it will disabled that session "Assign more Quota" button. My problem is that it disabled with another session "Assign more Quota" button in that same time. The another session does not reach 4 quota. How to separate control on disable button?

Also, there has another rule is that the minimum of each session quota should be at least 1 quota. If it reach 1 quota only, it will disabled that session "Delete Quota" button. The problem also same as assign more quota. That button will also trigger all session.

Here's a: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nf76z7?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: As far as I understand, you want to trigger some calculation on Quota change and Delete quota. What I would do probably is to create custom validator that iterates over all form arary items and calculates quota. Maybe also catching events from form controls on quota change would make it possible to recalculate quota on each change. Sorry I don't understand fully your issue, it's a bit haotic for me

Comment: Copy-pasted code is preferred to images of code as it can be [searched for and tested out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12892553) and in addition [Users from certain countries can't view hosted images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407369/12892553)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement you cannot use a single variable for each form array element.
You have to change the condition in [disabled]. Try the code below.

```
<button [disabled]="sessionFormArr.get('enrolTypeList')[ 'controls'].length>=4" type="button" style="margin-top: 15px;width: 180px;" (click)=" addNewAssignQuota(sessionFormArr.get('enrolTypeList')) " > 
    assign More Quota 
</button>


<button [disabled]="sessionFormArr.get('enrolTypeList')[ 'controls'].length <= 1" type="button" (click)=" deleteAssignQuota( sessionFormArr.get('enrolTypeList'), j ) " >
    Delete Quota
</button>
```

The above code works fine with the stackblitz code.